ubuntu terminal split session and broadcast commands
I've seen someone do this:
open multiple terminal sessions.
Go in ssh inside different machines.
Select group broadcast functionality.
give the same command to every ssh session, eventually remove broadcast, give commands to a single terminal and then broadcast again.
Can the ubuntu gnome terminal do that? what terminal should I install to get that functionality?

similar. can you do that with the gnome terminal? i found out I can do that with Terminator.

Nope, you can use clusterssh as suggested there instead, and Terminator is also mentioned there.

I've been told that it is Terminator, you use ctrl shift o or ctrl shift e and then select group and then brodcast group.
